# does every affine closed subscheme have an open affine neighborhood?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a scheme and $D\subset X$ be a closed affine subscheme. Under what conditions must there exist an open affine $U\subset X$ containing $D$?

The situation I'm imagining is this: $f : X\rightarrow S$ is a smooth projective curve over an affine scheme $S = \text{Spec }R$, and $g : S\rightarrow X$ is a section. Then $g(S)$ is a closed affine subscheme of $X$. Must $g(S)$ be contained in an affine open of $X$?

**A separate but related question:** Must $X - g(S)$ be affine?

Comment: [Hironaka's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka's_example) shows that not even every finite set of closed points needs to be contained in an affine open. So in general, the answer to the question that is the title of your post is no.

Comment: If you're thinking about the union of all $\mathbb F_p$-points (say in $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb F_p}$): these are contained in $D_+(f)$, where $f$ is any irreducible homogeneous polynomial of degree $> 1$. E.g. $x^2 + xy + y^2$ if $p = 2$, or $x^2 + y^2$ if $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: @Remy What is $D_+(f)$?

Comment: (Cf. Hartshorne, §II.2, p.76) It's the principal affine open of $\operatorname{Proj} S$ corresponding to the nonvanishing of $f$.

Comment: @Remy Oh of course you're right. I'm an idiot.